# React Native Expo Camera

Tags: react-native, expo

The react native expo camera example gives errors like _Camera is not defined https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/camera.html but I see others have gotten it to work [here](https://expo.io/@julezkiano/camera-demo)

Does anyone have some basic code on how to make use of the camera module? Or debug why the documentation example isn't working?

Comment: Same here, you got any camera code work's in expo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got same issue, after a lot of research Expo Camera is added from v20.I was using v19.0. I am new to Expo and did not realize it was added in v20 [here](https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-v20-0-0-is-now-available-79f84232a9d1). Problem is solved after upgrading react-native expo version to v20.
.[basic code for camera in expo is here](https://github.com/expo/camerja)

*edit in package.json*

```
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-20.0.0.tar.gz",

"expo": "20.0.0-alpha.4",

"react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
```

*edit in app.json*

```
"sdkVersion": "20.0.0",
```

- Delete your project’s node_modules directory and run `npm install`
- Reopen your project in XDE and press “Restart” to clear the packager cache

Comment: This example works for me also https://github.com/expo/camerja 
Where the docs for some reason didn't

Comment: @GregBenner, not sure if this was true when you made your comment, but at this time the `cameraja` example project does not work with the newest version of Expo. The docs you were reading may have been for a more recent Expo version than you were running.

Comment: @ChidG it's working for me. this is my expo and react version

    "expo": "20.0.0-alpha.4",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-20.0.0.tar.gz"

Comment: @AnjalSaneen that's good. The current version of Expo is 22.0.0, and I had to change some parts of the code to make the example project run.

Comment: does each expo version has their own syntax or what ? @ChidG

Comment: @NaveenDINUSHKA There are small changes to the API in each version, as there are in most early stage software projects. In this case there were obviously a few changes to the camera module over those few versions, which meant the example was out of date. Not too hard to debug and fix though.

Comment: @NaveenDINUSHKA Yes, last version they change to ```camera.takePictureAsync``` from ```camera.takePicture``` and return object also.